# Fade effect without overlapping each other

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, bxslider

I'm using bxSlider. What I want to do is a fade effect **without** items collapsing on each other.

Here's what I want to make:

[image]

Old item will be faded out **completely**, then new item will come up.

Here's a demo with low and high transition speed: http://jsfiddle.net/QLy7Q/2/

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  speed: 600,
  easing:'ease'
});
```

I also tried different types of easing methods, none of them worked as I wanted. (See options here http://bxslider.com/options)

Although I increase the 'speed' parameter, it only expands the time of transition and items still overlap each other. bxSlider has many options/callbacks so I believe I can achieve that, but couldn't figure out how.

Answer (score 1):

Aww, YES. I did it with a help from a coworker. Just add fadeOut to onSlideBefore callback.

```
$('.bxslider').bxSlider({
  mode: 'fade',
  speed: 1200,
  easing: 'ease',
  onSlideBefore: function($slideElement, oldIndex, newIndex){
    $('yourSliderItem').eq(oldIndex).fadeOut(400);
  }
});
```